# ng-Options is not refreshing the wired label when drop-down changed

Tags: angularjs, ng-options

Following Scott Allen's first code (simple) [sample](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2013/06/19/using-ngoptions-in-angularjs.aspx), after drop-down entry changes the wired ng-model is not refreshing this

> {{engineer.currentActivity}}

Browser: FF 50.1.0

Angular: 1.5.9

jQuery:  1.7

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="EngineeringController">
        {{engineer.name}} is currently : {{engineer.currentActivity}}
        <div>
            choose an activity:
            <select id="agDDLClient" ng-model="EngineeringController.currentActivity" ng-options ="act for act in activities">
            </select>
        </div>
        <input type="button" ng-click="what()" value="check" />
    </div>
```

JS:

```
var aIS = angular.module("app", []);
aIS.controller("EngineeringController", function($scope, $http)
{
    $scope.engineer = {
    name: "Dani",
    currentActivity: "Fixing bugs"
};

$scope.activities =
[
    "Writing code",
    "Testing code",
    "Fixing bugs",
    "Dancing"
];

$scope.what = function(){ alert($scope.engineer.currentActivity);}
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ng-model` value should be `engineer.currentActivity` instead of `EngineeringController.currentActivity` as you are trying to alert the `$scope.engineer.currentActivity` inside `what()` function.

**Working demo :**

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('EngineeringController',function($scope) {
    $scope.engineer = {
        name: "Dani",
        currentActivity: "Fixing bugs"
    };

    $scope.activities = [
        "Writing code",
        "Testing code",
        "Fixing bugs",
        "Dancing"
    ];

    $scope.what = function() { 
        alert($scope.engineer.currentActivity);
    };
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="EngineeringController">
        {{engineer.name}} is currently : {{engineer.currentActivity}}
        <div>
            choose an activity:
            <select id="agDDLClient" ng-model="engineer.currentActivity" ng-options ="act for act in activities">
            </select>
        </div>
        <input type="button" ng-click="what()" value="check" />
    </div>
```

Comment: Just went back and saw Scott's HTML is using "engineer.currentActivity". What I did was copy and paste, don't know what happened on me. :(

Answer (score 0):

Change to  `ng-model="engineer.currentActivity"` instead of  `ng-model="EngineeringController.currentActivity"`

and also your controller code should be follow this

```
var aIS = angular.module("app", []);
aIS.controller("EngineeringController", function($scope, $http)
{
    $scope.engineer = {
    name: "Dani",
    currentActivity: "Fixing bugs"


$scope.activities =
[
    "Writing code",
    "Testing code",
    "Fixing bugs",
    "Dancing"
];

$scope.what = function(){ alert($scope.engineer.currentActivity);}
});
```

Comment: About the code you posted, I don't get it. Except yours missing a closing bracket "}", rest are the same.